# How to develop project with your local library in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, npm

I have a library which is written in typescript and is normally installed via npm. Currently I'm developing some app that requires it and I often need to make some changes in it as well. The ideal situation for me would be if I just could edit my library directly and see the changes in my app. I've tried with `npm link` but without success. How can use it with typescript?

Answer (score 1):

You can `npm link` to your library but it needs to be compiled first.

Lets say you have project P that depends on library L, which are all local to you:

```
./repos
    ./P
        project.json
    ./L
        ./src
        ./dist
        project.json
```

The file `/repos/L/project.json` should have a entry `main` pointing to the main file of the library **in dist**. You have to compile the library (using `tsc`) to generate dist.

Then you do

```
$ cd repos/L
$ tsc      # or maybe npm run build
$ cd ../P
$ npm link ../L
```

And that's it.

Comment: OK, but this way I would need to compile it every time I make a change in the library. I would like to work on .ts files directly. That's why I wrote that I couldn't get it working with `npm link`